Determine if injected service was called in UnitTest
I am trying to test to see if injected service was used within the service I am testing and wondered if that will be possible at all?
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IInjectedService _injectedservice;
    public MyService(IInjectedService injectedService1)
    {
        _injectedservice = injectedService1
    }

    public string Method1(int value)
    {
        _injectedservice.Generate();
    }
}

I have UnitTest to test MyService class, but I want to determine if the InjectedService was used or ran within the MyService. In my test I am mocking the IInjectedService injectedService1 service to pass through

You have basically 2 options to deal with this. One would be to create your own "Fake" implementation of IInjectedService then use that in the test with whatever logic you want (like tracking a boolean internally to detect if it was called and expose it in the object). I won't be covering that here unless you want to go with that approach (let me know).
The other, more common approach, is to just use a mocking library. The example below relies on NSubstitute.
public sealed class MyServiceTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CallingMethod1GeneratesInjectedService()
    {
        // Arrange
        var injectedService = Substitute.For<IInjectedService>();
        var myService = new MyService(injectedService);
        
        // Act
        myService.Method1(1);

        // Assert
        injectedService.Received().Generate();
    }
}

(make sure to change the test name based on the names of your real objects and methods as obviously it doesn't make much sense right now)
You can also opt to use other mocking libraries with similar APIs if you want.
